# Card.io ios integration with localization

Tags: ios, card.io

I am trying to integrate Card.io sdk to my iOS app. I'd like to do a simple localization for CardIO ui, as changing Cancel button title or "Hold credit card here" hint text.

I've found this android demo on github, and it's simply using strings.xml file to do this.(I guess, couldn't try yet.)
https://github.com/card-io/android-scan-demo/blob/master/app/res/values/strings.xml

How can i do this in my iOS app? Shouldn't there be a file attached to card.io ios SDK like this strings.xml above.

Edit: I'm using Card.io sdk 3.0.5.

Regards,

Comment: There should, but apparently there's no `Localizable.strings` file in the `en.lproj` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Josh from card.io here. We released localization support in version 3.1, which is available now.

Comment: Hey @Josh Bleecher Snyder, I have not found any documentation on the localization support. Has it been released? Thanks!

Comment: Hasn't been released yet, but fear not, we've not forgotten about it (or about updating here when it happens). It really is close, I promise. :)

Comment: How do you implement it please ?