# iOS: Card.io how do you localized it

Tags: ios, localization, card.io

I would like to localize some text in card.io but can't find a way to do it.
There is a SO post who claim it is possible but i can't find how. ([Card.io ios integration with localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671474/card-io-ios-integration-with-localization))

Thanks !

Comment: [Check This out From Person belonging to Card.io ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14691202/5332817)

Comment: This is exactly the post linked in my question....

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Qordoba SDK](https://www.qordoba.com/for_mobile) to manage the localization for Card.io and for the full app too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i prefer to translate Card.io with a file than adding another 3rd party sdk to my app.